# Convert dynamic XML to HTML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform a XML into a readable HTML.
Below I am putting a sample part of my XML that I am unable to transform myself and needs some help.

The XML may have a variable number of columns that will be generated by the name `col1,col2---colxxx`. Here If ITEM=Label I am adding `<B>` before their names.

Sample XML is  as follows

```
<Root>
    <row ID="1" ITEM="Label" col1="visit no">
    <row ID="1" ITEM="Data" col1="1">
    <row ID="1" ITEM="Label" col1="Date">
    <row ID="1" ITEM="Data" col1="8/11/2018">
    <row ID="1" ITEM="Label" col1="PatName" col2="DocName" col3="DocName" />
    <row ID="2" ITEM="Data"  col1="Sam Hul" col2="Dr Mike" col3="Vegas Hospital"/>
    <row ID="2" ITEM="Data"  col1="Dan Brown" col2="Dr Matt" col3="California Hospital"/>
```

I want to convert the above XML into below HTML content. The col1,col2, col3 are being generated using a loop. so they will have names will have an incremental number after col.

The expected output HTML is

```
   <Table>
    <tr><td><b>visit no</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Date</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>8/11/2018</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>PatName</b></td><td><b>DocName</b></td><td><b>DocName</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sam Hul</td><td>Dr Mike</td><td>Vegas Hospital</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dan Brown</td><td>Dr Matt</td><td>California Hospital</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is what i am trying at this moment.Buts its generating the single TR

```
<tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="row/@*">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: @michael.hor257k  How to count number of tags with colxxx in each row node

Comment: Why would you need to count them? -- Please post your stylesheet so we can fix the issue you are having problems with. We are not here to write your code for you.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for responding.  I am unable to write any thing for this part of code. If you can direct me towards any thing i will write it my self. Just give me a head start.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Please see the updated question. I have added code into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***---  edited in response to changed reqirement ---***

That's a strange way to build a table, but if that's what you want, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[starts-with(name(), 'col')]"/>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="@*[../@ITEM='Label']">
    <th>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </th>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to a **well-formed (!)** XML input:

**XML**

```
<Root>
    <row ID="1" ITEM="Label" col1="visit no"/>
    <row ID="1" ITEM="Data" col1="1"/>
    <row ID="1" ITEM="Label" col1="Date"/>
    <row ID="1" ITEM="Data" col1="8/11/2018"/>
    <row ID="1" ITEM="Label" col1="PatName" col2="DocName" col3="DocName" />
    <row ID="2" ITEM="Data"  col1="Sam Hul" col2="Dr Mike" col3="Vegas Hospital"/>
    <row ID="2" ITEM="Data"  col1="Dan Brown" col2="Dr Matt" col3="California Hospital"/>
</Root>
```

the (rendered) result will be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there is a slight problem. :) There are many Labels in that XML. This code is printing the all the headers at top. I just need to put then in sequence as they are in XML and just need to bold where ITEM='Label'.

Comment: Please edit your question and show an example of input with multiple `label` rows, and the expected output.

Comment: Isn't this solution assuming that @* will return the attributes in a predictable order? I think the `apply-templates select="@*"` should have a child `xsl:sort select="name()"`

Comment: @MichaelKay I believe it's quite safe to assume that (a) the order of attributes is the same in each row and (b) the processor will return them in document order (even though it is not obligated to do so).

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks a lot. it worked like charm . I

Comment: @michael.hor257 There's nothing in the spec that justifies the assumption. For one row, @* might deliver (col1, col2, col3), and for the next row it might deliver (col2, col3, col1). I agree most processors will deliver the attributes either (a) in the order written, or (b) in an order determined by hashing the names, both of which will lead to consistent orders, but there's nothing in the spec that requires this.

Comment: @MichaelKay "*there's nothing in the spec that requires this*" I have already agreed with you on this. Still, I believe it's safe to assume that no processor will go out of its way to randomize the order just to prove the point. Apparently you agree with me on this, so why don't we leave it at that. Anyone worried about such possibility can add the `xsl:sort` instruction as per your suggestion. Although I would make it `<xsl:sort select="substring-after(name(), 'col')" data-type="number" />` in case there are more than 9 columns.